# Any ideas on how to generate code based NLU Data

Tags: generative-models, ai, chatbot

I am working on a Generative AI project. I wish to explore stuff possible using "Code inputs".

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
      <img src="Gsuite.jfif" alt="Gsuite Logo"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Consider this simple example. My current method is to brute force some basic examples like for the anchor tag I have this: `[<a]{"entity":"tree_tag", "role":"anchor"} href=[https://google.com]{"entity":"link", "role":"href"}>` and for the image tag I have this: `[<img]{"entity":"void_tag", "role":"image"} src=[Gsuite.jfif]{"entity":"link", "role":"src"} alt=[Gsuite Logo]{"entity":"params", "role":"alt"}/>`.

I have added several examples simples like this for most of the available html tags. My idea is that all the html tags are detected by the AI model as seperate entities including the parameters for every html tag like href, src, height, alt, etc. I wish to generate more examples with such brute forced examples purely based on Html codes. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?